# Can anyone tell me what is this plant with white trumpet flowers?

Tags: identification, flowering

Not sure what this beautiful flower located in Arizona is. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it belongs to Datura, a genus of poisonous plants, but I'm not sure about the exact species. Looking at the shape of the leaves it seems to me that it could be [Datura wrightii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura_wrightii).